Simplified canvas builtin
related
The golfing languages 05AB1E and Vyxal have a "canvas" builtin that draws a string on a ASCII grid. In this challenge, you'll be implementing a simplified form of this.
You should take a string of ASCII characters, along with a list of directions as integers 0-7, where 0 is directly upwards and the rest continue clockwise - 1 is up-right, 2 is right, etc up to 7 being up-left.
7 0 1
 \|/
6-x-2
 /|\
5 4 3

For example, given the string abcde and the directions 0,2,5,6:
Draw a at the center, then move up (0) and draw b:
b
a

Then move right (2) and draw c:
bc
a

Then move down-left (5) and draw d, overwriting the a:
bc
d

And finally move left (6) and draw e:
 bc
ed

For a more complex example that I won't work through, given the string octagon! and the directions 1,2,3,4,5,6,7, you should draw:
 ct
o  a
!  g
 no

Empty space should be filled with spaces, and you can output with any amount of leading and trailing whitespace so long as the pattern at the centre is still correct. There will always be exactly one more character than directions, so that one character can be drawn at the centre.
You may take directions as any subset of the integers from 0 to 10 inclusive, or take them as direction vectors [1,-1],[0,1],[-1,0] / complex numbers / similar, and/or reorder them in any way. The input string may contain spaces.
This is code-golf, shortest wins!
Testcases



Input
Output




[1,1,1,1], "aaaaa"
    a   a   a   a   a    


[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],"octagon!"
 ct o  a!  g no 


[2,4,2,4,2,4,2,4],"staircase"
st    ai    rc    as    e


[1,1,1,1,1,1],"s s s s"
      s           s           s           s      


[2,2,2,2,0,0,6,6,4,4], "overwriting"
  iti  n rovgrw


[2,2,2,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,0,0,1,5,2,2,2,1,5,4], "+--+|+/+--+|X/+--X/+|"
  +--+ /  /|+--+ +|  |/ +--+  


[6,7,0,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2],"spiralspiralspiralspiralspir"
   spir    l       a       r   als  i  r   p p  i    is   ps  r l      a  a    l    rips  




"The golfing languages 05AB1E and Vyxal have a 'canvas' builtin" cries in Charcoal, Turtlèd, SOGL, Paintbrush, and... Canvas =P

@LuisMendo Yes, and I'll actually edit it into the question this time.

05AB1E, 3 bytes
2ŠΛ

Try it online.
Explanation:
Simply uses the 05AB1E Canvas builtin this challenge is based on, with additional length = 2 argument.
2    # Push 2
 Š   # Triple-swap using the two (implicit) inputs
     #  STACK: 2,string,directions
  Λ  # Use the Canvas builtin with these three arguments
     # (after which the result is output immediately implicitly)


Charcoal, 7 bytes
ＧＨ✳✳Ａ²Ｓ

Attempt This Online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: PolygonHollow is Charcoal's path text writing function. It has two modes of operation, one where each direction and path length is specified and one where there is an array of directions and a fixed path length. Here Directions is used to specify an array expression as the directions. However PolygonHollow takes 0 as right and 2 as up, so I have amended the test case appropriately. The path length of 2 is inclusive so that each subsequent step draws one additional character.
9 bytes to take input where 0 is up and 2 is right:
ＧＨ✳✳⁻χＡ²Ｓ

Attempt This Online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: As above but subtracts all the directions from 10 (PolygonHollow automatically reduces modulo 8) to get them into Charcoal format.
An alternative 9 bytes to take input where 0 is up and 2 is right:
ＧＨ✳✳Ａ²Ｓ‖↘

Attempt This Online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: As the first solution but reflects the canvas to get the desired result.

Bash, 182 bytes
s="$1"
e='echo -en'
shift
$e "\033[$#B\033[$#C"
for d;{
$e ${s:i:1}
case $d in
7|0|1)$e "\033[1A"
;;&
0|4)$e "\033[1D"
;;&
3|4|5)$e "\033[1B"
;;&
5|6|7)$e "\033[2D"
;;
esac
let i++
}

Attempt This Online!
-13 bytes by looping with for d (implicit over all remaining args) instead of c-style loop.
makes heavy use of terminal escape sequences, and is the very first time I actually used fall-through switch statements anywhere!
provide the string as first argument (with quotes if it has spaces), then provide the numbers separated by spaces.
since this only works on a terminal, here are a few screenshots (i've verified that all test cases work):

notice the huge whitespace. instead of computing how much whitespace i'll need, i simply offset to the number of commands, that way even the worst case won't try to move outside of bounds (which will fail silently)




low hanging fruit for someone else: you can probably get an easy outgolf by replacing echo -en '\033[' characters with the literals of the appropriate escape code. i'm not doing that.

JavaScript (ES6), 102 bytes
Expects (directions)(characters), where directions is an array of [dx,dy] vectors and characters is a string. Returns a matrix of characters.
d=>s=>[...d,m=[...d+=x=y=d.length].map(_=>[...d].fill(" "))].map(([X,Y],i)=>m[y][x]=s[x+=X,y+=Y,i])&&m

Try it online!
(post-processing: the matrix is joined and some whitespace is removed for readability)

You are allowed to take direction vectors e.g. up-right = [1, -1], which saves... quite a few bytes

You can use backticks for the fill and drop the parentheses.

@Shaggy That would not really return a "matrix of characters" anymore -- although it would not change anything once joined.

C (GCC), 264 bytes
x;y;a;z;b;w;main(n,v)char**v;{for(v++[3]=calloc(4*n,n=strlen(v[1]));v[2][x+n+(y+n)*n]=*v[1]++;++*v)a=x<a?x:a,b=x>b?x:b,w=y<w?y:w,z=y>z?y:z,x-=**v%4?(**v&4)/2-1:0,y-=(**v-=2)%4?(**v&4)-2:0;for(y=w;y<=z;y+=2)for(x=a;x<=b+1;++x)putchar(x>b?10:v[2][n+(y+n)*n+x]?:32);}

Attempt This Online!

261 bytes

254 bytes

Something does not look right with the octagon! example.

Uiua, 19 17 bytes
⬚@ ⌝⊡∩▽’⍜⇌◰.\+⊂⊸⧻

Try it!
⬚@ ⌝⊡∩▽’⍜⇌◰.\+⊂⊸⧻
                ⊂⊸⧻  # prepend (length, length)
              \+      # cumulative sum coordinates
         ⍜⇌◰.        # mask the last occurrences of each coordinate
      ∩▽’             # keep the coordinates and characters with the mask
⬚@ ⌝⊡                # create an array with the characters at the specified coordinates

Has a lot of leading whitespace (see bash answer). You can use ⬚@ ⌝⊡-¤⊸/↧+⊸⧻∩▽’⍜⇌◰.\+⊂0 to remove it for +4 bytes.

Wolfram Language (Mathematica), 67 bytes
SparseArray[Reverse/@(FoldList[Plus,{l=Tr[1^#2],l},#]->#2),2l," "]&

Try it online!
Input a list of direction vectors and a list of characters. Output a matrix of characters as a SparseArray.

Jelly, 17 bytes
ZẈ;"$ÄZŒṬ€a"o@/o⁶

Try it online!
Takes a list of [dy, dx] pairs on the left and the string on the right, returning a list of lines.
Z     Z              Under transpose:
  ;"$                Prepend to each column
 Ẉ                   the length of that column,
     Ä               then cumulative sum each column.
         €           For each resulting coordinate,
       ŒṬ            create a grid with a 1 at those coordinates and 0s elsewhere,
          a"         and replace the 1 with the corresponding character.
            o /      Reduce the list of grids by logical OR
             @       reversed so that later characters overwrite earlier ones,
               o⁶    then replace any remaining 0s with spaces.


C64 BASIC, 122 bytes
1inputs$,d$:?cH(147):p=1524:fOi=1tolen(s$):pOp,aS(mI(s$,i,1))-64:p=p+vA(mI("1011519190894909",1+vA(mI(d$,i,1))*2,2))-50:nE


Try in emulator

Python 3, 142 bytes
f=lambda x,s,p={},c=0,S=sorted:s and f(x[1:]+[c.real,c.imag],s[1:],{**p,c:s[0]},c+x[0])or[[p.get(i+j*1j,' ')for j in S({*x})]for i in S({*x})]

Try it online!
-42 bytes thanks to UnrelatedString
Takes complex numbers as input and returns a (square) 2D array of characters with loads of whitespace

The "etc." seems to suggest that taking complex numbers directly is acceptable in the spirit of direction vectors. In any case, very nice!

Yes, taking complex numbers is fine.

@UnrelatedString Ah I missed that, it saves rather a lot, thanks!

APL+WIN, 102 bytes
Prompts for string followed by a vector of dx and then dy:
s←⎕⋄x←(1+|⌊/x)+x←+\0,⎕⋄y←(1+|⌊/y)+y←+\y←0,⎕⋄m←((⌈/y),⌈/x)⍴' '⋄i←1⋄⍎∊(⍴x)⍴⊂'m[y[i];x[i]]←s[i]⋄i←i+1⋄'⋄m

Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic

Vyxal, 20 bitsv2, 2.5 bytes
2ø^

Try it Online!
Bitstring:
01000011111001001000

Same idea as the 05ab1e answer but without the need for explicit swapping (it uses overloads). Uses the built in canvas digraph with length 2.
